# ¿Como puedo poner un enlace dentro de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Quisiera declarar un enlace dentro de un JavaScript `<a href="#"></a>`, tengo los siguientes datos que mando llamar:

```
<script>
 var plant = [
{nomb: "ESCUELA 1",
        dirc:"CENTRO, 405",
        lat:25.52689,lng:-80.674479,
        enlc:"http://index.html",
        correo: "correo@gmail.com",
        telefono: "(452) 1404512",
        ciudad: "Lugar 1",
        oferta: "Preparatoria",
        lic: "Administración, Educación",
        pos: "Administración",
        online: "Preparatoria"},

      ];


$(document).ready(function(){
        var enlace = plant[indice].nomb;
        $("#indic").html(indice);
        $(".titulo__plantel").html("Plantel "+plant[indice].nomb);
        $(".correo_plantel").html(plant[indice].correo);
        $(".telefono__plantel").html(plant[indice].telefono);
        $(".direccion__plantel").html(plant[indice].dirc);
        $(".ciudad").html(plant[indice].ciudad);
        $(".enlc").html(plant[indice].enlc);
        $(".oferta").html(plant[indice].oferta);
        $(".lic").html(plant[indice].lic);
        $(".pos").html(plant[indice].pos);
        $(".online").html(plant[indice].online);
</sript>
```

y los mando imprimir en un div en html

```
<div class="content3">
   <span class="oferta"></span>
   <span class="lic"></span>
   <span class="pos"></span>
   <span class="online"></span>
</div>
```

como podría ponerle a `lic: "Administración, Educación"` un enlace diferente, para que envíen a paginas diferentes al oprimirlo? necesito de su ayuda, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrias intentar lo siguiente:

```
var plant = [
{nomb: "ESCUELA 1",
        dirc:"CENTRO, 405",
        lat:25.52689,lng:-80.674479,
        enlc:"http://index.html",
        correo: "correo@gmail.com",
        telefono: "(452) 1404512",
        ciudad: "Lugar 1",
        oferta: "Preparatoria",
        lic: [{
               "Administración":"data",
               "Educación":"data"
        }],
        pos: "Administración",
        online: "Preparatoria"},

      ];
```

Entonces dependiendo lo vas a llamar ya sea Administración o Educación tendra una data diferente.